# There exists a basis of $V$ like $B$ such that $P$ is the basis transition matrix from $B$ to $C$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

An $n$-dimentional vector space $V$ is given.  $P \in M_n(F)$ is invertible and $C=\{w_1,\dots,w_n\}$ is a basis of $V$.

Prove that there exists a basis $B$ of $V$ such that $P$ is the transition matrix from $B$ to $C$.

Note : Is it enough to say that $B=P^{-1}C$? It seems too easy ... I think i'm wrong

Comment: Well, you must prove that $\{P^{-1}w_1,\cdots,P^{-n}w_n\}$ is actually a basis.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Is this even right ?

Comment: Yes it's right, but you must prove it.

Comment: @sigmabe any hint on how to do that?

Comment: Do you know the determinant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To finish the question, you must prove that $\{P^{-1}w_1,\cdots,P^{-1}w_n\}$ is a basis.  To do this, you must show linear independence and spanning.

- Linear Independence.  Suppose that $a_1P^{-1}w_1+\cdots+a_nP^{-1}w_n=0$.  Then, multiply by $P$ on the left to get $a_1w_1+\cdots+a_nw_n=P0=0$  Since $\{w_1,\cdots,w_n\}$ form a basis, $a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_n=0$.  Therefore, $\{P^{-1}w_i\}$ are linearly independent.
- Spanning.  Let $b\in V$.  Since $w_1,\cdots,w_n$ is a basis, there exist $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ so that $a_1w_1+\cdots+a_nw_n=Pb$.  Then, $a_1P^{-1}w_1+\cdots+a_nP^{-1}w_n=P^{-1}(a_1w_1+\cdots+a_nw_n)=P^{-1}Pb=b$.  Therefore, $\{P^{-1}w_i\}$ is spanning.

Comment: @Bye_World I wish you hadn't deleted your answer.  It was a good answer!

Comment: Your answer is strictly more comprehensive so I didn't see a point in keeping it.  Thanks, though.